# How to get the ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset in dev independent pixels for an ItemsControl with CanContentScroll true

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a listbox with CanContentScroll true, but others that are false.

And i'm writing a behavior that needs to extract the scrollviewer from it and calculate the vertical scroll offset in device independent pixels.

Since the CanContentScroll can be either true or false I sometimes get logical item units while other times physical pixels.

So I need to calculate the pixel values in case CanContentScroll is true.

For an example: when the listbox is scrolled by three items VerticalOffset will give 3. How to convert this 3 to the vertical pixels used by the items (which can vary in size)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot calculate the values in pixels without *effectively* setting CanContentScroll="False".

To know the size in pixels you would need to create the containers of all the items and sum up the heights of all the containers. To do that you will need to generate all the containers first. Which would mean that you *effectively* lost virtualization and *effectively* set CanContentScroll="False". In that case why use CanContentScroll="True" in the first place?

What Nikolay's code tries to do is take on the burden of doing yourself what CanContentScroll="False" does without giving you the smooth scrolling that you would have otherwise gained.

More importantly what problem does the physical offset solve that you cannot solve with the logical offset if you know that CanContentScroll="true" always?

Comment: I agree with you, my solution is wrong. You have to work with logical offset when you use CanContentScroll.

Comment: you are right, virtualization screwed everything up, so we found another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just sum sizes of scrolled items like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var scroller = GetScrollViewer();
  var listBox = GetListBox();
  double trueOffset;
  if (scroller.CanContentScroll)
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)scroller.VerticalOffset; i++)
  {
      var listBoxItem = (FrameworkElement)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
      trueOffset += listBoxItem.ActualHeight;        
  }
  else
      trueOffset = scroller.VerticalOffset;        
  this.Title = trueOffset.ToString();
}
```

This simple code works well for listbox with variable size items

Comment: This works only when the listbox is defined with inline ListBoxItems in the content. When using an ItemsSource and datatemplates for the data contained in there `Items.OfType<ListBoxItem>()` is always empty, because Items contains the Model/ViewModel objects. So unfortunately this is of no use to me and probably most of us :/

Comment: You can get ListBoxItem through ItemContainerGenerator:
`var listBoxItem = (FrameworkElement)this.Box.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)`

Comment: It seems to work like this, can you put that in the answer please?

Comment: Added it to the example in answer

Comment: This is not going to work if you are using a virtualizing panel (which a listbox would by default). You're likely to only get the containers for the elements that are in view (and maybe some just before/after). The fact is you can't get a pixel value. When you turn on CanContentScroll you are allowing the ItemsPanel (as provided by the ItemsPanelTemplate) have a chance to control the scrolling. If that implements IScrollInfo then it determines the scroll range, values and what changing the offsets mean.

Answer (score -1):

I would try a different approch.

Embed your listbox with a Scrollviewer and disable the scrolling behaviour of the listbox itself.

You can than can measure the scrollviewer VerticalOffset outside the listbox.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer, Path=VerticalOffset}"/>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>B</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>C</ListBoxItem>
```

Comment: This is crazy. If you've set CanContentScroll="False" in ListBox you get the physical offset anyway. Why do you even want to wrap it into a Scrollviewer?!?

Comment: Because the Listbox will not fit into a surrounding grid. That's why you need to wrap it into a ScrollViewer to enable scrolling and to get the correct VerticalOffset.

Comment: But all that can be done by the ListBox's Scrollviewer. The question is about getting the physical offset when CanContentScroll="True". The deeper question is how do you get the physical offset when you are using virtualization.

Comment: In order get the physical offset you don't need to set CanContentScroll="true". The solution I described is much more easy to achive that.

Comment: You've completely missed the question. The question is can you get the physical offset when CanContentScroll="True"? OP already knows how to calculate physical offset when CanContentScroll="False".